# Pythonic way to update a Pandas dataframe using apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, apply

To all the Python Panda gurus.

Below is a snippet of code. I basically want to apply a correction to my existing dataframe by calling out to a function and then update my dataframe column. However, apply() gives back a new dataframe.
So I am a bit stuck how best, in pythonic way, can I implement the below:-

As you will see below, I am unnecessarily doing for loop and then setting the dataframe at the correct index value.

Ideally I would like to do a apply per label, which is the commented section below the for loop where I loop through the index.

The code is:

```
## run a cluster analysis on the yield levels
def run_cluster(data_df, num_clusters = 7):
    column = "Yield"
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=0).fit(data_df[column].values.reshape(-1,1))
    # centroids, var = kmeans(data_df[column].values, num_clusters)
    centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    data_df["Cluster"] = kmeans.labels_

    for label in np.unique(kmeans.labels_):
        idx = data_df[data_df["Cluster"] == label].index
        mad = np.median(np.abs(np.sum(centroids[label] - data_df[data_df["Cluster"] == label]["Yield"])))
        # data_flt = data_df[data_df["Cluster"] == label]
        for i in idx:
            data_df.ix[i,"Cluster"] = correct_clusters(data_df[data_df.index == i],centroids[label], mad)
        # new_data_df =    data_df[data_df["Cluster"] == label][["Yield","Cluster"]].\
        #                                 apply(lambda x: correct_clusters(x,centroids[label],mad))
        # new_data_df.to_csv("I:\\output\\new_df.csv")
    # for index, row in data_df.iterrows():


    # data_df["Cluster"] = assignment
    return centroids

def correct_clusters(row, centroid, mad):
    if np.abs((row.ix[:, "Yield"] - centroid).values) > mad:
        return -99  ## <- Special cluster which needs to be ignored!!
    else:
        return row.ix[:, "Cluster"].values[0]
```

Comment: Are you using `apply` at column level or the whole dataframe level ? You should use - `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].apply(lambda x : demofunction(x))`.

Comment: `df.loc[my_index_filter,'col_2'] = df.loc[my_index_filter,['col_1','col_2]].apply(lambda x: demofunction(x, param_1,param_2), axis=1).                      def demofunction(x,param_1, param_2): if criteria_1: x[1] = 0 else: x[1] =-99`. However, when I look at my changed dataframe, I see only NaNs. Any clue?

Comment: Apologies. Was making a silly error on the demofunction(). All good. Thanks for your quick help!!